# Calculating Increasing Rents Year over Year by Month Depending on Lease Start Date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a couple of properties that I am trying to generate an excel formula that will calculate rent increases year over year based on when the lease starts for a tenant. Spent time in excel trying to generate the formula but I'm still off with the formula created. I am trying to have 3 static variables which are:

- Column O = fixed percent of an increase for rent
- Column P = the month the lease starts (will be a # 1-12 so that excel knows which month the increase should start it, when I did this initially, I did this based on the lease always starting in January and ending in December which will not always happen)
- Column D = starting initial amount for rent

=IF(MOD(ROW() - ROW($D$2), 12) >= MOD($P$2 - 1, 12), IF(MOD(ROW() - ROW($D$2), 12) = MOD($P$2 - 1, 12), $D$2 * (1 + $O$2), $D$2 * (1 + $O$2)^(INT((ROW() - ROW($D$2) - MOD($P$2 - 1, 12)) / 12))), $D$2)

I got to the above formula; however, something is not correct.

1.The first 12 months there should be no increase, but it shows a value of $1890 for month 1. This should just be 1800 for the first 12 months, month 13 should show an increase since the lease starts on month 1 or on the month of January.

2.The increase occurs correctly for month 13, which is the next consecutive year, but on month 25 the correct value for the increase is not calculated correctly. I expect a value of $1984.5 but it's returning the value of $1890 which is the previous years increased rent.

3.I try to manipulate the month lease value, so that depending on when the lease starts, excel will know when the rent should be increased. If it starts in January or 1 the rent will increase January of each consecutive year, if it starts in February the rent increase will occur in February for each consecutive year, if it starts in March the rent will increase each March for each consecutive year, so on and so forth.

[[image: Excel Formula Rental Increase]]

Comment: This `=$D$2*(1+$O$2)^INT((ROW()-2)/12)` or `=LET(α, 48, $D$2*(1+$O$2)^INT((SEQUENCE(α)-1)/12))`

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed. The only thing is how do I account for a lease starting In Feb/March/April etc? The above assumes that the leases start on Jan. I just need to make sure I can account for a lease that may start on months 2-12 so that excel knows where in the month to apply the correct rent increase on. Hope this makes sense

Comment: "Column O = fixed percent of an increase for rent" <-- no cell with values is in column O of the screenshot

Comment: @DBT what is the difference if the lease starts in month 1 versus 6. The rent increases after 12 months for either of the options, or?

Comment: @DBT so in that scenario if the month lease starts from March for example then will the `1800` to be followed for the 24 months or will it be something else, can you show some examples please

Comment: @P.b Sir, realized technically we are asking the same question to OP LOL!! Just saw your comment, may be refresh is not working

Comment: Also, if the `SEQUENCE` used in the comment of Mayukh worked that means you don't use Excel 2010. By tagging you do, the possibilities are limited compared to later/current version of Excel.

Comment: Thank you all for your help on answering this question and providing me your feedback. There really is no difference I guess I could actually start the sheet with the month the lease starts and the formula would work correctly. Using Office 365, thank you again to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an extra variable to use for the number of years to be in the forecast.
I also "assumed" that the first year would be **this** year *(2023)*.

*Please note that I used references to `P3`, `Q3` and `R3` as you showed in your screenshot, instead of `D2`, `P2` and `O2` as you wrote in your question. Change the references if appropriate to whatever you really have.*

[image]

If you have Microsoft 365, you can use this formula in a single cell, and the results will `SPILL`

```
=HSTACK(
    MAKEARRAY(
        12 * S3,
        1,
        LAMBDA(r, c, DATE(2023, Q3 + r - 1, 1))
    ),
    MAKEARRAY(
        12 * S3,
        1,
        LAMBDA(r, c, R3 * (1 + P3) ^ INT((r - 1) / 12))
    )
)
```

[image]

If you really have Excel 2010, and none of the advanced functions, you can use the following functions:

```
Date: =DATE(2023,$Q$3+ROWS($1:1)-1,1)
Rent: =$R$3 * (1+$P$3)^INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/12)
```

Enter in some row in adjacent cells and fill/drag down for as long as you want to predict the future rents.

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for but could not get to it. Thank you for your help with this, I really appreciate it!